# how to add a new property in jsonb field type?

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I have a jsonb field type named "attributes" in my table, it contains like below:

"attributes"

```json
{ 
  "pid": 5,
  "extras": {
   "option1": true,
   "option2": false
   }
}
```

how to add a new property called option3 with value false?

```
{ 
  "pid": 5,
  "extras": {
   ...,
   ...,
   "option3": false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is by using json_set ([Official Documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html)) but the right way to use it would be:

```
UPDATE <table_name>
SET attributes = jsonb_set(attributes, ARRAY ['option3'],to_jsonb('false'::text), true )
WHERE attributes->>'pid' = '5';
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Postgres Online Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html) is the best resource for learning more about JSONB operators.  (Make sure you select the version you are using in the upper left if you are not on the current version, 13 as of this writing.)

You can use the `jsonb_set` function, e.g.

```
UPDATE demo
SET attributes = jsonb_set(attributes, '{extras,option3}','false', true /* create the field if missing */)
WHERE attributes->>'pid' = '5';
```

See a working example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/655bb/3).

Comment: Your answer will become pretty useless once the links go stale; please consider adding the solution to the answer itself.